# How to set up a real Gearman Environment

Tags: php, gearman

Gearman drives me crazy. I know all the tutorials all the presentations all the How tos but i'm not getting the Information i need.

***My plan***

I have one client who sends the jobs to the one job-server which is on the localhost. On this Server ( Home-Server ) runs the Website and the DB. Now i have two ( later more Worker-Server ) which we will call W1 and W2. At these Servers the hard work should be done and they should get the Jobs from the Home-Server where Gearman-Job-Server is installed. The Jobs are synchroun, which means that the client waits until the Tasks gets finished.

But I dont know how to do this. Every tutorial i find only told me how to set up Gearman when Clients and Workers are running on the same Machine.
On the Home-Server i installed gearman-job-server and the PHP gearman API with PECL.
At my clients which i handle with supervisord i call:

```
$gmc = new GearmanClient();
$gmc->addServer();
```

Which should send the Tasks to the localhost Job-Server which should get than to one of the two free Worker-Server. Right?

At the worker.php on thw Worker-Server W1 and W2 - which get also handled with supervisord - the following is written

```
$gmworker= new GearmanWorker();
$gmworker->addServer('Home-Server-IP', 4730);
```

Now the Worker-Server should get the Tasks from the Home-Server? Do I have to install gearman-job-server at W1 and W2 or is the PECL PHP Gearman API everything i need? And do i have to configure the Worker-Server?

I really hope you can explain these questions to me, that i can understand Gearman.

Some more Information:
When I tipe at Home-Server

```
gearmand -vvv -u root --listen=127.0.0.1
```

Output is just:

- INFO Starting up
- INFO Listening on 127.0.0.1:4730 (6)
- INFO Creating wakeup pipe
- INFO Creating IO thread wakeup pipe
- INFO Adding event for listening socket (6)
- INFO Adding event for wakeup pipe
- INFO Entering main event loop

After the last line the shell isnt doing anything more. I even cant tipe a new command.

Even more Infos.

I checked that Gearmand is running at the Home-Server.

```
ps -e|grep gearman
```

Output:

- 1460 ?        00:00:00 gearmand

When i now give the command on the Worker-Server

```
/usr/sbin/gearmand -u root -vvv --listen=Home-Server-IP
```

I got following Error.

- INFO Starting up
- FATAL _listen_init:bind:99
- INFO Shutdown complete

I really did nott get whats going wrong with my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of gearman are you using? The output of the error message makes me think it is quite old.

Why are you trying to run it as root?

Comment: Yeah, your right. It is an old Gearman Version should be 0.13.
But i probably got things running. How come?
On next morning i installed telnet on every Server and it worked. I cant descripe what i exactly did, but it simple worked on the next day.